# make synchronous request to mysql in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I need to make sql query to mysql inside another function and I receive result of query after my main function returns value

```
    connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM `sys_menu_top` WHERE `Type` = 'top' AND Active = 1 ORDER BY `Order`", function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (rows) {

          async.each(rows, function (row, callback) {
            row.children = [];
            connectionPool.getConnection(function (err, connection, sql) {
              connection.query("SELECT * FROM `sys_menu_top` WHERE Parent = " + row.ID, function (err, children, fields) {
//                                console.log(children);
                if (!err && children.length > 0) {
                  children.forEach(function (child) {
                    row.children.push(child);
                  });
                  row.children.push(children);
                }
                else {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              });
            });
            callback();
          }, function (err) {
            if (err)
              console.error('error looping array\n\n');
          });
          process.nextTick(function () {
            cb(null, rows);
          });          
        }

      });

    });
```

my code returns rows without children but I can receive children in console after function returns result of first query. I need to put children for each row into this row and then return result.

Comment: Why aren't you using a join for this?

Comment: I don't have indexes on this table and I can't modify db structure. So if I will have 1Gb table with 8kk lines it would be a problem. And I will expand this code with if else statements so in some cases I don't need to make second query at all (unnecessary join on 1Gb table without indexes isn't a good idea). This question not about MYSQL but about node.js

Comment: You do have an index... `WHERE Parent = " + row.ID`

Answer (score 0):

I know it has a different approach but it could be worth to try what follows:

```
async.waterfall([
      function (callback) {
        var q = "SELECT * FROM Rows";

        executeQuery(q, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) { callback(err); return; };
            if (rows) {
                callback(null, rows);
                return;
            }
        });
      },
      function (rows, callback) {
        console.log(rows);
        for (k in rows) {
            if (rows[k].Parent != null) {
                child = rows[k].id;
                parent = rows[k].Parent;

                for (j in rows) {
                    if (rows[j].id == parent) {
                        if (!rows[j].Children) rows[j].Children = [];
                        rows[j].Children.push(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        callback(null, rows);
      }
   ], 
   function (err, rows) {
            console.log(rows);
});
```

What I get with my test Table is:

```
[ { id: 1, Parent: null },
  { id: 2, Parent: 1 },
  { id: 3, Parent: 1 } ]
[ { id: 1, Parent: null, Children: [ 2, 3 ] },
  { id: 2, Parent: 1 },
  { id: 3, Parent: 1 } ]
```